# Trivial answers in comment box

Tags: discussion

We are often told not to use the comment box for answers, but sometimes this seems like the obvious thing to do. Here's the [example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62778/how-to-use-%E9%A0%AD%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B-or-%E9%A0%AD%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B-literally-to-indicate-bowing) that prompted me to ask this question. **Edit:** someone supplied an answer after I asked this question but this does not always happen.

In my opinion this comment satisfactorily answers the question and it doesn't seem worthwhile writing a full answer. So what should we do now?

1) Do we just ignore it and wait for it to rear its head again later (and then ignore it again ...)?  This doesn't seem useful.

2) Should someone turn the comment into a proper answer? This feels a little like stealing credit, but maybe its okay if you make it clear that the answer was derived from the comment.

3) Should we have a close option along the lines of 'Answered trivially in comment box'?

4) Slap people with a wet fish when they use the comment box for answers? I don't think this is right either. People are busy and we should be grateful that they take the time to write a comment. I don't think we want to discourage this.

5) Something else?

Answer (score 3):

> In my opinion this comment satisfactorily answers the question and it doesn't seem worthwhile writing a full answer.

Oops.. I didn't think that comment would answer the question.. sorry! ><

---

> So what should we do now?

I think #2 would be fine, since I've seen people do that several times.
Some posted their answer as "Community Wiki".

> "If a question is answered in the comments section, you can always post that comment as an answer; just mark it Community Wiki and make sure you give credit to the original commenter." (from [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1479/9831))

I think it'd be also fine to post a comment to encourage them to turn their comment into an answer.. I've seen people do this, too. (Not everyone followed the suggestion, though, of course...)

And I think it'd also be okay to just flag the comment... Then the mod may (or may not) delete the comment, and leave a comment saying "Please don't try to answer questions in the comments section."

Comment: And.. this thread is partly related, maybe... https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/9831