# What's up with these old questions showing up on the front page?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

Lately there's been a lot of old questions popping up on the main website, with a status that reads **modified X hours ago [Community](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)♦ 1**.

On the profile for this account, it becomes clear that this is some sort of bot that keeps this website clean and managed and tries to bring attention to older questions, but isn't every hour a bit excessive on a website this calm?

There's also the concern that these questions may have been asked by users who have left this platform a long time ago without deleting their accounts, which would mean that new activity might ultimately miss the mark on having a positive impact on this website. But that's just speculation, of course.

Comment: I was also thinking to ask this... To be honest, I even think it's hazardous. Some of the new questions are buried because of this, and it's a little hard to find.

Comment: See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1479/9831 Questions with answers scored 0 or lower automatically get bumped up to the top. Most of the answers in the threads recently bumped up had lost a score from one deleted user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Chocolate writes in the comments, these are the afterquakes of one of our moderators leaving the site.

These questions had upvoted answers, whose votes were undone and thus landed in the Unanswered tab, where questions are bumped to the top to receive more attention. Such bumps are usually quite rare, as [unanswered questions are only bumped only every 120 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/299332), i.e. about three times per year. But we suddenly have a lot of unanswered questions (and we will probably see the same wave again in about 120 days).